# How can I find the Fourier transform of the following function?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

$$\text{f(t)}=-3\sin(50\pi t)\cdot 6e^{\frac{-|t|}{2}}$$

First I wrote the sinusoidal in terms of complex exponentials then after a minor cancellation and using the distributive property I got:

$$9ie^{i50\pi t}\cdot e^{\frac{-|t|}{2}} - 9ie^{-i50\pi t}\cdot e^{\frac{-|t|}{2}}$$

How can I proceed from here? I do not know if I can write it in Fourier Transform form somehow or simplify it further by writing it to the power of just one $e$ by using $e^x\cdot e^y=e^{x+y}$ since I have $|t|$ on one of them...

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(t)=\sin(a t)$, $g(t)=e^{-b |t|}$, and $h(t)=Af(t)g(t)$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{h\}(\omega)&=\frac1{2\pi}\left(\mathscr{F}\{f\}*\mathscr{F}\{g\}\right)(\omega)\tag1
\end{align}$$

The Fourier transform of $f$ is

$$\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\omega)=i\pi (\delta(\omega-a)-\delta(\omega+a))\tag2$$

and the Fourier transform of $g$ is

$$\mathscr{F}\{g\}(\omega)=\frac{2b}{\omega^2+b^2}\tag3$$

Putting $(1)$-$(3)$ together we find

$$\mathscr{F}\{h\}(\omega)=\frac{iA}{2}\left(\frac{2b}{(\omega-a)^2+b^2}-\frac{2b}{(\omega+a)^2+b^2}\right)$$

Now, set $A=-18$, $a=50\pi$, and $b=1/2$.

Comment: I never thought of using the convolution approach since in all my practice so far I haven't had to use it...

Comment: Also shouldn't it be $\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\omega)=i\pi (\delta(\omega+a)-\delta(\omega-a))$ instead of (2) since you brought $i$ to the numerator. And thanks a lot, btw.

Comment: That dpends on how one defines the FT.  I use $e^{i\omega t}$ as the kernel in the forward Fourier transform, not $e^{-i\omega t}$.

Comment: And you're welcome.  My pleasure.